# ColumnStore Index - Maximum Rows in a RowGroup - 1,048,576 OR 102,400?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I was trying to understand, the architecture of Columnstore Indexes - SQL Server 2016.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx#Anchor_4

Here, the minimum rows in a rowgroup to move in to the column store is mentioned as 102400, But it is also mentioned, that 1,048,576 rows are usually stored in a rowgroup. So how is this balance maintained?

-Yasub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different things..

> rowgroup
>   A row group is a group of rows that are compressed into columnstore format at the same time. A rowgroup usually contains the **maximum number of rows per rowgroup which is 1,048,576 rows**.

Pasted relevant part for 102,400 rows

deltastore
Used with clustered column store indexes only, a deltastore is a clustered index that improves columnstore compression and performance by storing rows until the number of rows reaches a threshold and are then moved into the columnstore.

During a large bulk load, most of the rows go directly to the columnstore without passing through the deltastore. Some rows at the end of the bulk load might be too few in number to meet the minimum size of a rowgroup which is 102,400 rows. When this happens, the final rows go to the deltastore instead of the columnstore. For small bulk loads with less than 102,400 rows, all of the rows go directly to the deltastore.

Few more usefull links..

1.How it works internally..
http://rusanu.com/2012/05/29/inside-the-sql-server-2012-columnstore-indexes/#more-1463

2.Best tutorial..

http://www.nikoport.com/columnstore/